# Get all keys of nsdictionary sorted alphabetically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, key, nsdictionary

I have got a NSDictionary with alphabets as keys. I want to get those keys sorted alphabetically . I have tried many methods but I am getting error on Sort() method. Can any one help me ????

Thanks in advance

Note:
 1) I don't want to get a sorted array of dictionaries 
 2) I don't want to sort the dictionary by means of the values
(I am getting a lot of answers for this )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can sort the keys this way:

```
let dictionary: NSDictionary = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2]
let sortedKeys = (dictionary.allKeys as! [String]).sorted(<) // ["a", "b"]
```

Swift 3:

```
let dictionary: NSDictionary = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2]
let sortedKeys = (dictionary.allKeys as! [String]).sorted(by: <) // ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply  :-)  . . . .  Other answers were killing me with errors  !!!!!!

Comment: Getting error 'sorted' is unavailable: call the 'sort()' method on the array

Comment: Thanks, this saved me lots of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 2.2**

You can sort like this in **Ascending Order**

```
let myDictionary: Dictionary = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2]
let sortedKeys = myDictionary.keys.sort()          // ["a", "b"]
```

**Descending Order**

```
let myDictionary: Dictionary = ["a" : 1, "b" : 2]
let sortedKeys = myDictionary.keys.sort(>)        // ["b", "a"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3**

```
    // Initialize the Dictionary
let dict = ["name": "John", "surname": "Doe"]

// Get array of keys

var keys = Array(dict.keys).sorted(by: >)
print(keys)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the "var keys" line. Did you mean to use allKeys?
   var keys = Array(dict.allKeys).sorted(by: >)
edit: still doesn't like that. I've gone to:
   var keys = (dict.allKeys as! [String]).sorted(by: >)